# Walk around Firefox's offline storage warning?

Tags: html, firefox, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I am developing an web app with HTML5 offline browsing support. I wrote a manifest file as shown below:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
audio/a.ogg

NETWORK:
*
```

When I visit my app in Firefox, A warning message prompts saying:

'*This website [192.168.2.14] is asking to store data on your computer for offline use. Allow, Never for this site, Not Now*'.
See https://dl.dropbox.com/u/83574968/ff-offline.png

I am using FF 14.0.1 stable on Ubuntu 12.04 and Chrome works fine. Apparently I can't control which browser end users use and it seems users tend to disable offline storage on seeing the warning message: [see here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120325135250AA7fSgx)

So, **is there any way to walk around this warning message in FF if I want to use offline storage?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's currently not possible. Removing that warning would allow developers to do some pretty horrible stuff

Here's an ongoing discussion on the subject:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648064#c1

[How a web application can download and store over 2GB without you even knowing it](http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/03/how-web-application-can-download-and.html)

Comment: Hmm... Interesting discussion and blog post. Thanks.